# Using Google Hangouts on Google Chrome: from time to time "Couldn't start the video call because of an error"

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

When I joined a Google Hangouts video conference with Google Chrome, from time to time, I get the error message

> Couldn't start the video call because of an error"
>   
>  Please check your firewall settings and try again.

I use the same computer (OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate) and the same network (Ethernet, on a University campus: 1 Gbps symmetric, ~3ms ping): the error sometimes appears, sometimes it works fine.

I don't have any firewall.

What could the issue be?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have to do a "Quit" in Chrome and then reload the hangout. It seems to happen if I leave the browser open for days.

Beware closing all the tabs doesn't seem to be the same as Quit, as the Chrome process stays around (at least for me).